# How to retrieve data from mutiple tables using common column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the data from the both tables by joining on the common column. But it's giving me the duplicates.

```
 ;WITH LocID AS
    (
    SELECT 1 AS LocID, 1 AS CommonID 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS LocID, 1 AS CommonID 
    ), 

    LocAddress AS(
    SELECT 456 AS AddressID, 'Address-1'AS 'Address',  'City-1' AS City, 'State-1' AS 'State', 1 AS CommonID
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 789 AS AddressID, 'Address-2'AS 'Address',  'City-2' AS City, 'State-2' AS 'State', 1 AS CommonID
    )

        SELECT L.LocID, A.Address, A.City, A.State FROM LocID L INNER JOIN LocAddress A ON L.CommonID = A.CommonID ;
```

The desired output would have only two rows as show below.

**LocID  Address   City    State**

1     Address-1 City-1  State-1

2     Address-2 City-2  State-2

Is there any way I can get this?

Comment: mysql does not have `CTE`

Comment: what's the current result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. The result is correct. If you want the output exactly like you mentioned above, the query should be like this :

```
 ;WITH LocID AS
    (
    SELECT 1 AS LocID, 1 AS CommonID 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS LocID, 2 AS CommonID 
    ), 

    LocAddress AS(
    SELECT 456 AS AddressID, 'Address-1'AS 'Address',  'City-1' AS City, 'State-1' AS 'State', 1 AS CommonID
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 789 AS AddressID, 'Address-2'AS 'Address',  'City-2' AS City, 'State-2' AS 'State', 2 AS CommonID
    )

        SELECT L.LocID, A.Address, A.City, A.State FROM LocID L INNER JOIN LocAddress A ON L.CommonID = A.CommonID ;
```

**EDITED** :

Or, you may consider to have 2 fields to join, like this :

```
 ;WITH LocID AS
    (
    SELECT 1 AS LocID, 1 AS CommonID 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS LocID, 1 AS CommonID 
    ), 

    LocAddress AS(
    SELECT 456 AS AddressID, 'Address-1'AS 'Address',  'City-1' AS City, 'State-1' AS 'State', 1 AS CommonID, 1 AS LocID
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 789 AS AddressID, 'Address-2'AS 'Address',  'City-2' AS City, 'State-2' AS 'State', 1 AS CommonID, 2 AS LocID
    )

        SELECT L.LocID, A.Address, A.City, A.State FROM LocID L INNER JOIN LocAddress A ON L.CommonID = A.CommonID AND L.LocID = A.LocID ;
```

Comment: I have two rows in the both tables for the given CommonID.

Comment: Based on your sample, you need to focus on LocID, or both with CommonID. If you still rely solely on CommonID, with this data, you will never get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing query contains 2 rows that are unioned, just output that and you don't need the "common id" to do this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 456 AS AddressID, 'Address-1'AS 'Address',  'City-1' AS City, 'State-1' AS 'State'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 789 AS AddressID, 'Address-2'AS 'Address',  'City-2' AS City, 'State-2' AS 'State'
    ) AS d
```